# Code, which searches dataframe for string/part of string and shows Complete if all complete in certain column

Tags: python, excel, automation, jupyter-notebook

I have 2 excel files. One "to be searched", second with values (string) to search "IWPs to search".

Goal is to find IWPs (values) which meet certain criteria (say 'complete') in "to be searched" file, and show the complete percentage from overall (complete + not started).

To be searched:

[image: IWP, QVD Status]

IWPs to search:

[image: IWPs to search for]

I know how to find IWPs statuses one by one, but would like to know how to seach multiple string values from excel file.

Comment: Please [do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), add the information as text (within code fences etc.) instead.

Comment: Find() with wildcards…